# How to make custom listview row layout with ckeckbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, row

How to make custom listview row layout in android that include checkbox and make it selectable or clickable?

I tried to make it with my own layout but the row become not clickable when i include checkbox in that layout? Why?

Comment: Please specify a platform like c# and ASP.NET etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check the link

http://appfulcrum.com/?p=311

http://alltechsolution.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/android-listview-with-checkbox-retain-state/

Comment: first link is wrong, but close enough. should be: http://appfulcrum.com/2010/09/18/listview-example-4-custom-layout-checkbox-imagebutton-textview/

Answer (score -1):

[here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)!!!!